# Why would a molten alloy need to be jettisoned into low-to-medium orbit to cool as part of the manufacturing process?

Tags: space, metals, microgravity

I'm working on a game idea and one of the mechanics I had in mind was making it so a premium material had to be formed by jettisoning it into orbit and letting it cool there while you guard it with your ship. As this metal cools and reaches the desired state, it would also become a beacon that would draw players (in PVP servers) or hostile NPCs (in PVE servers) to your location who would attack you to try to steal the metal for themselves.

Once the material is cooled and secured, the alloy can be machined down to the shapes you need. Melting down the metal again would ruin it until you jettison it into space to cool all over again. I'm having trouble figuring out what would make this metal only possible to create in low-to-medium orbit vacuum. I also wanted to make sure these conditions were prohibitively difficult to recreate on a planet surface. In the backstory for this setting, the alloy would have been made in orbital foundries that have since been destroyed beyond repair or have crashed into the planet below. Jettisoning it into orbit is the cheap way to do it in the absence of such foundries.

The best I can come up with is that maybe one of the materials in the alloy are so dense they would settle out to the bottom of the crucible before the metal can fully cool, but that only solves the gravity issue. Maybe it needs to be hit with cosmic rays?

What are some ways that vacuum and microgravity might affect a molten alloy that could be beneficial? This material is meant to be able to handle a lot of weight, being used as a high end structure/frame material for player built vehicles.

Comment: If the material is valuable enough to raid the orbital factories for, that in itself may solve the second part of your problem (why cool it outside) : The cost of losing some batches and their escort fighters will be much more bearable than the cost of repairing/replacing an entire factory.

Comment: Honestly: It wouldn't. While "space is cold," it's actually not as easy as it may sound to cool things in space. The Space Station needs [large radiators](https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2001/ast21mar_1) to accomplish this task, for example. The problem is that there is no air. Sure, what gases exist are cold, but they are so incredibly sparse that transferring any significant amount of heat to them is actually extremely hard.

Comment: The vacuum of space would actually cause things to cool very slowly, which is desirable for some grades of steel.  Also, removing gas from the alloy would occur naturally.  Definitely not a full answer, but points that would support your concept.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Uniformity and sterility.**

Your alloy is most likely a HEA, or a [high-entropy-alloy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-entropy_alloy), extremely high-performance alloys that are difficult to make with even today's techniques. They gain their unique properties through their atomic structure, which requires precise and equal amounts of multiple different elements spread evenly throughout their structure to achieve the desired effects, but have the potential to surpass many of our materials that we have today.

[image: Crystal structure of a HEA.]

Vacuum and microgravity provide two things: uniformity, and sterility. Microgravity prevents the process of sedimentation and buoyancy, meaning all these elements within your molten alloy will be evenly and thoroughly mixed to maximise the super-material properties of the HEA. The vacuum is also *clean*. There is very little else there. It provides the opportunity to create ultra-pure materials with minimal defects, something which is very difficult under normal conditions.

These two factors - which are very difficult (in the case of sterility) or flat out impossible (in the case of microgravity) - can ensure that the material is only effectively manufactured in the specific conditions of orbital vacuum, and presents the ideal option as a high-end and expensive material.

The ISS has been considered a candidate for manufacturing of HEA [before](https://www.issnationallab.org/iss360/materials-research-society-fall-2019-ryan-reeves/#:%7E:text=lenses%2C%20among%20others.-,High%2DEntropy%20Alloys,-My%20talk%20on).

Comment: They might be well suited to microgravity manufacturing, but HEAs would be a poor fit to the described process of slow cooling in open space. Instead of a HEA, you'd get a low-entropy mix of different phases and crystal formations of various compositions. This process would be more suited to single-crystal superalloys.

Comment: Bulk properties such as high degree of uniformity of a coating or of a spherical shape are also much easier to obtain in weightless conditions. High performance ball bearings or other machine parts might also be manufactured there.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but setting aside the cooling speed issue raised in comments above, wouldn't your description also mean that it would be most desirable to do this not in orbit, but in deep space, where there could be an absolute minimum of gravitational forces at play? Orbit might be better than surface elevation, but why not go all the way?

Answer (score 9):

## To reduce lattice defects and to cold weld it

Your scientists have developed a very special alloy which is a mixture of some quite expensive metals and some synthetic elements from the island of stability. The micro g environment of space is needed to make it, as even the small gravity of earth destabilizes the very complicated alloy structure and it's very hard to generate a vacuum hard enough to make it. The alloy, filled with random holes in its structure is ejected into space and hammered into shape, the hammering pushing out the unwanted ions and molecules that got in, you use ultrasonic soundwaves to form the exotic structure and it is then cooled into shape.

Then you need to cold weld it. Cold welding is when you hold unionized metals close together and they merge because the metal just bonds to other metal ions. This is much easier to do in space because it has strong vacuums, and also the cold welding means there's no weak points on the structures you built. Attempts to do this on earth or in an enclosed space have failed due to the weaker vacuums.

The alloy is extremely expensive to make due to the rare ingredients and pirates coming to attack and steal it, and the thermal signature from the alloy is easily spotted from afar due to its emission spectrum, which is what colours it emits when heated up.

Answer (score 7):

### The "beacon" effect is the key

> As this metal cools and reaches the desired state, it would also become a beacon that would draw players (in PVP servers) or hostile NPCs (in PVE servers) to your location who would attack you to try to steal the metal for themselves.

While this was most likely only a gameplay aspect at first, this "beacon" effect could also be used as the reason why you have to cool it in the vacuum of space.

If the cooling metal radiates strongly enough that it can be picked up by other people and tracked down, then there is a high chance those radiations could have side effects on the nearby ecosystems or machines.

Your ships are already made to negate the effects those radiations could have on their crew, but those effects could have very harsh consequences on the fauna and flora of a planet. Of course, you could make facilities with that in mind, but the cost in time and resources would be very high, even more so for an individual.

#### Although... why not both?

If you managed to setup the right tools and protections to deal with this radiation on a planet, you'd still have the issue of pillagers. As I understand it from your explanation, this material is very valuable, to the point that attempts at stealing it by force are very common, if not always expected. Settling in one place may allow to prepare solid defenses, but it also means the attackers can prepare in advance, since they know exactly where you'll be preparing your metal. You'll have stronger defenses, but your foes will be much more deadly.

As a matter of fact, this kind of "fortified forge" setup could work for large, wealthy groups, and they could lead to massive battles (wink wink group PvP/PvE raids wink wink). However for individuals or small groups, this would not be sustainable, and the space option stays the best.

Having this procedure in space also means you can do it just about anywhere, without any previous preparation, which gives less time for potential invaders to prepare and react. You won't be able to do it for long before you get overrun, but you can always run away when that happens and do it again once you've lost some attention.

Comment: This seems the best so far +1

Comment: Getting it away from the player's fortified defenses was part of the reason I wanted the material to need to be dumped into space where I don't plan on allowing players to build. Though the part about it being easily detected is a good point. Maybe an intermediate stage the metal takes is radioactive and it is decaying, not cooling. EDIT: Oh, hey, others suggested the radiation idea, too.

Answer (score 4):

Similar enough?

**Instead of an alloy, you are harvesting trapped antimatter in orbit.**

[THE DISCOVERY OF GEOMAGNETICALLY TRAPPED COSMIC-RAY ANTIPROTONS](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2041-8205/737/2/L29)

> ABSTRACT The existence of a significant flux of antiprotons confined
> to Earth's magnetosphere has been considered in several theoretical
> works. These antiparticles are produced in nuclear interactions of
> energetic cosmic rays with the terrestrial atmosphere and accumulate
> in the geomagnetic field at altitudes of several hundred kilometers. A
> contribution from the decay of albedo antineutrons has been
> hypothesized in analogy to proton production by neutron decay, which
> constitutes the main source of trapped protons at energies above some
> tens of MeV. This Letter reports the discovery of an antiproton
> radiation belt around the Earth...   PAMELA data show that the
> magnetospheric antiproton flux in the SAA exceeds the cosmic-ray
> antiproton flux by three orders of magnitude at the present solar
> minimum, and exceeds the sub-cutoff antiproton flux outside radiation
> belts by four orders of magnitude, constituting the most abundant
> source of antiprotons near the Earth.

Your apparatus sweeps up and contains the antiprotons.  They are a super valuable energy source.  Your containment devices become more valuable as they are deployed and fill with the antiprotons.  It is these devices that pirates and rivals are coming to claim.

This happens in orbit because that is where the antimatter is.  The remaining Macguffin is why you don't collect your half-full containers when you see pirates coming.  Maybe if you get them too soon all the antimatter spills out.

Comment: Perhaps they're not in quite orbit, but on a carefully-managed trajectory maintaining low acceleration and very low jerk. Accelerating the container too hard or too suddenly would make the antiprotons touch the side of the container.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - I like that.  Because of the possibility of the whole thing blowing up, which is the salt and pepper of every space battle game.

Answer (score 2):

The "had to be formed by jettisoning it into orbit [to] cool" concept seems artificial to me.  However, there are good practical reasons to work metal in vacuum and in microgravity, (including some stated in previous answers) which if made clear make the concept less artificial.

In the following reasons (which I think were not previously mentioned) *product* means the target material, and *material* means other production stuff.

(1) The product may have a melting point higher than other available materials.  Working in microgravity allows heating the product without needing a crucible that could melt.  For example, suppose you need to boil tungsten to make the product, eg tungsten or tungsten carbide foam.  This would mean dealing with metal at 5555℃ (10030℉), a temperature that would vaporize an ordinary crucible.  Note, radiant heating works fine in vacuum; conductive heating would require contact; and convective heating is not an option if there is vacuum between the heat medium and the melt medium.  Possibly, plasma-arc heating (eg with argon gas plasma) would work ok in vacuum.

(2) The product might be much larger than would fit into a typical contained space — for example, you might have an extrusion process producing a girder a few hundred kilometers in length.  In an orbit providing microgravity, the extrusion can be oriented to extrude with near-zero torque acting on it.  Also, wind forces ordinarily are negligible in hard vacuum.

(3) Most high-temperature metal-working on earth, in atmosphere, requires expensive measures to prevent oxidation, hydrogen embrittlement, trapped slag and gas bubbles, uneven cooling leading to trapped stresses, etc.  Working in vacuum clears away several of these issues.  However, microgravity would keep common slag-removal methods and possibly some bubble removal from working.  For the former, flux gets stirred into molten metal, which gathers slag and floats to the top; and "float to top" doesn't work in microgravity.  For the latter, gas bubbles also won't "float to top"; but on the other hand, vacuum will "draw out" all bubbles that have enough internal pressure to overcome surface tension of the metal or material being worked.

Comment: "there are good practical reasons to work metal" (+1) in the vast emptiness of space where no one GAF. Slag gets thrown to the left. Ingots go on the right. Anyone takes from my pile: you shoot 'em. Ain't no one selling nobody storage space... *in space*, ffs.

Answer (score 2):

## Massive radiation release & alchemy:

Your material is made with a metallic lattice that can only be created from a radioactive element and in a gravity-free environment. Otherwise the material is too reactive. Inside the material are seeds of proton or alpha particle releasing materials that are artificially accelerated to decay by radioactive bombardment. So the two materials accelerate the conversion of your radioactive isotope to a relatively harmless and stable element. The lattice structure of the original element remains, but if melted, the crystal structure collapses.

Your process is somewhat slow, and massively radioactive, operating like a huge fission reactor. The accelerated decay means that as soon as the decay process is done, the material stops pouring out radiation. Vast amounts of material is decaying, but only a small amount is "done." Since the need of your civilization is vastly higher than when they started making the material, and the relative slowness of the process, there is a significantly higher demand than supply due to the delay.

The added fun is that the materials are going to be floating in space amidst a field of hot, radioactive chunks of material busily bombarding the other bars with radiation. So plenty of hazards, and the material finishing decay is detectable at light speed.

Answer (score 1):

The big orbital foundries could isolate it well enough that outgassing from your ship wouldn't contaminate it.  However, that isn't viable with the amount of mass your ship can devote to it and you have a big decontamination problem after every trip into atmosphere.  Hence the workaround of letting it cool through the critical temperature out by its lonesome.

I can't think of any reason it would act like a beacon but it might have emissions lines while cooling that are distinctive.